# Finding the coefficient of $x^n$ in a multiplication of two summations

Tags: combinatorics

Given:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {{n+2 \choose 2} x^n} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-x)^n}$$

How do we find the coefficient of $x^n$?

Comment: You take the coefficient of $x^k$ in one sum, multiply it by the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ in the other, and then sum over $k$ from zero to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If you imagine multiplying out the sum above, you'll get a bunch of terms, each of which is the product of one term from the left sum with one term from the right sum.  These terms will be of the form

$\binom{j+2}{2} x^j \cdot x^k = \binom{j+2}{2} x^{j+k}$

So you just want to collect all the terms where $j + k = n$.  How many ways are there for this to happen?  Well, $n = 0 + n = 1 + (n-1) = \cdots = n + 0$, so the $x^n$ term is just

$\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{j+2}{2} x^j (-x)^{n - j}$

$= \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{j+2}{2} (-1)^{n-j} x^n  $

$= (-1)^n \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \binom{j+2}{2} x^n  $

Comment: You forgot the $(-1)^n$.

Comment: Thank you; I've fixed it now.

Comment: And then calculate the that sum?

Comment: and why can we put the $(-1)$ outside?

Comment: It doesn't depend on j, so you can factor it out of all the terms.

Comment: and what's left is to calculate the sum?

Comment: One way to calculate $\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j{j+2\choose2}$ is to calculate it for a few small values of $n$, say, $n=0,1,\dots,7$ and then look it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: @TheNotMe: Yes.  Note that $\binom{j+2}{2}$ is a quadratic polynomial in $j$, so if you know how to calculate sums of squares you are done.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** the 2nd sum is a geometric progression. The 1st sum is the derivative of a geometric progression.

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: I think he's saying that you could calculate both sums in closed form, multiply them, and then take the Taylor series of the result.  (Which is a nice way to do *this particular problem*.)  If that's the case, it doesn't really help explain the concept of how to multiply generating functions in general, though.

Comment: But how do you do that, if there's a derivative in there (actually a second derivative)? You just get a nasty mess, don't you?

Comment: The closed form is not bad; it's just $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3(1+x)}$.  I don't know of an efficient way to extract the Taylor series of a rational function, but I feel like this is something that Arnol'd would yell at modern mathematicians for.

Comment: @Daniel McLaury: I agree, it is not best method.

Comment: @TonyK: I consider these sums as formal series.

Comment: @Boris: But then we're back to square one, aren't we?

Comment: @TonyK: Certainly, but it's a little easier.